# Unable to trigger response message when sending initial message

Tags: elm

I am unable to trigger a response message when sending an initial message.

I have a button:

```
  button
    [ class "register"
    , value "Create Account"
    , onClick Submit
    ]
```

I have the following messages:

```
type Msg
    = Submit
    | Response (Result Http.Error JsonProfile)
```

The message handler that is invoked via button click is the following:

```
update : Msg -> Form -> ( Form, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Submit ->
            ( model, runtime.tryRegister model Response )
        ...
```

Here's the other message handlers:

```
update : Msg -> Form -> ( Form, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Submit ->
            ( model, runtime.tryRegister model Response )

        Response (Ok json) ->
            ( model, Navigation.load <| "/#/portal/1" )

        Response (Err error) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

My tryRegister implementation is the following:

```
tryRegister : Form -> (Result Http.Error JsonProfile -> msg) -> Cmd msg
tryRegister form msg =

        let
            jsonProfile =
                JsonProfile 1 form.firstName form.lastName form.email

            newMsg v =
                msg
        in
            Cmd.map (newMsg <| Result.Ok jsonProfile) Cmd.none
```

Here's the client code to the elm module depicted above:

```
onRegistration : Registration.Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
onRegistration subMsg model =
    let
        ( form, _ ) =
            Registration.update subMsg model.registration
    in
        case subMsg of
            Registration.Submit ->
                ( { model | registration = form }, Cmd.none )

            Registration.Response result ->
                case result of
                    Result.Ok jsonProfile ->
                        let
                            newUser =
                                jsonProfileToProvider jsonProfile

                            newState =
                                { model
                                    | registration = form
                                    , portal =
                                        { initPortal
                                            | provider = newUser
                                            , requested = Domain.EditProfile
                                            , linksNavigation = False
                                            , sourcesNavigation = False
                                        }
                                }
                        in
                            ( newState, Navigation.load <| "/#/portal/" ++ getId newUser.profile.id )

                    Result.Err _ ->
                        ( model, Cmd.none )
```

**Expectation:**

I expect that when I click the button, that navigation takes place.
However, nothing happens and I don't understand why.

[**Video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdCFDITvW0g)

Source code is [here](https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza/blob/master/Client/app/Controls/Register.elm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `Cmd.map (...) Cmd.none` is not sufficient to force another update cycle. You can force an update cycle by sending an always-succeeding task with `Task.perform`.

```elm
tryRegister : Form -> (Result Http.Error JsonProfile -> msg) -> Cmd msg
tryRegister form msg =
    JsonProfile 1 form.firstName form.lastName form.email
        |> Result.Ok
        |> msg
        |> Task.succeed
        |> Task.perform identity
```

*Note: There are good reasons not to do this, as [outlined here](https://medium.com/elm-shorts/how-to-turn-a-msg-into-a-cmd-msg-in-elm-5dd095175d84), but we'll ignore those for now to fit the framework you've outlined*

However, that alone will not make your code work. You have a nested `update` call which ignores the `Cmd` returned from `Register.update`:

```elm
( form, _ ) =
    Registration.update subMsg model.registration
```

That underscore has the effect of blocking all commands generated from the child `update`. You will need to retain that child `Cmd`, map it to the parent `Cmd`, and return it instead of `Cmd.none` inside all `onRegistration` cases. For example:

```elm
onRegistration : Registration.Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
onRegistration subMsg model =
    let
        ( form, subcmd ) =
            Registration.update subMsg model.registration

        regcmd =
            Cmd.map OnRegistration subcmd
    in
        case subMsg of
            Registration.FirstNameInput _ ->
                ( { model | registration = form }, regcmd )

            ...
```

Comment: I'm really thankful for your detailed answers. How can I give back?

Answer (score 0):

`Cmd.none` is used in `tryRegister` function, which does nothing.  I think you should use `Http.send` which actually fires the message loop after the http request completes.

The shortest example...,

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Submit ->
            (model, Http.send Response request)

        Response ... -> 
            ...
```

Comment: I have that code as well. However, I still don't observe the navigation to be invoked: tryRegister: https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza/blob/master/Client/app/Services/Gateway.elm

Comment: In addition, I thought that Cmd.none was being mapped to a Cmd Msg that is ultimately the response msg that I passed in as an argument for tryRegister to invoke?

Comment: Here's a video of my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdCFDITvW0g

Comment: I suggest you to add Debug.log to observe Navigation.load is being evaluated, or not.  In my answer, I assumed it is NO (due to use of Cmd.none), but it may have been wrong.